# Nvidia Quadro k1000m GK107GLM Drivers Problem Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics, kde

I have installed KDE Plasma on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 PC which has an NVIDIA Quadro graphics card, but I need the drivers for that video adapter.

My specs are:

- [HP Elitebook 8570w](http://www.hp.com/united-states/campaigns/workstations/images/datasheet_8570w.pdf)
- 8 gigs of RAM
- Nvidia Quadro k1000m

Installing from Driver Manager > `Nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-390 (Recommended Driver)` causes problems.  Every time I boot into Ubuntu

1. The login screen jumps to my second screen from the built-in laptop screen\
2. The screen brightness is not working
3. It alters the KDE Plasma resolution, and
4. I can't see the Ubuntu logo and instead get the HP logo.

How do I solve this?

**Edit:**

Downloading the drivers from nvidia's website didn't worked.  it asked me to disable Nouveau drivers after doing that. they installed successfully but my screen resolution feels like 1024x768 but it show its 1920x1080.

I was using Pop OS the graphics were working fine. so I decided to check which driver version they have installed. it was nvidia 440.44. so installed them on my Ubuntu. but no luck :(

Comment: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/153717/en-us is the driver from NVIDIA for your onboard K1000M Quadro adapter. Have you tried installing using NVIDIA's drivers instead of what you find in Software and updates?

Comment: @K7AAY I didn't. I'm downloading them to try

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am using the Quadro drivers from Nvidia's website for my Elitebook with Quadro 1000m and can confirm that they are working good.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Are you using gnome or kde? because I'm using kde  and I've tried downloading and installing the drivers they install successfully but resolution is not working correctly. it shows its 1920x1080 but feels like 1024x768. I was using Pop OS the graphics were working fine so I though to check which driver version they have installed. it was nvidia 440.44 so installed them but no luck :(

Comment: @Kevin J Sorry for the delay, Your post reminded me that it was time to update my Nvidia drivers.  I am using gnome. I have an older Quadro 1000m card, recommended driver is NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.132, I see that Nvidia is recommending NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-418.113 for your card.